# How can I cause systemd to wait starting a unit until a certain condition is fullfilled

Tags: systemd, boot, systemctl, luks

I'm still struggling to understand boot sequence dependency configuration in systemd unit files.  I've read the manual (`systemd.unit`).

I tried to add dependencies using the `After=` and `Requires=` lines to my unit configuration file. However it still regulary fails during system startup because systemd starts it too early before a needed resource (in my case a LUKS encrypted volume) has become available. In my tests it looked like systemd is ignoring these configuration lines.  The content of these lines is also **not** listed when using the command:

```
systemctl list-dependencies
```

to check for configured dependencies.
**Example**: My device volume is `/dev/dm-6`. How can I specify that systemd should wait with starting my unit until this device has finally appeared?

If I start my unit manually in a terminal window after boot using this command:

`systemctl start` *name_of_my_unit*

it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`systemd.device` might be what you want

> A unit configuration file whose name ends in ".device" encodes information about a device unit as exposed in the sysfs/udev(7) device tree. This may be used to define dependencies between devices and other units.
> ...
> Device units are named after the /sys/ and /dev/ paths they control. Example: the device /dev/sda5 is exposed in systemd as dev-sda5.device

Links

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.device.html
- https://superuser.com/questions/851846/how-to-write-a-systemd-service-that-depends-on-a-device-being-present
- https://www.enricozini.org/blog/2017/debian/systemd-07-devices/

Answer (score 0):

`RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/volume`

Where the path is in the required mount point.

Comment: I can't use RequiresMountFor= because in my case the problem is the device, which is only mounted later on within the unit. More specific: The LUKS device and the cryptsetup is handled in a Xen dom0 domain and the systemd unit in question is starting a virtual machine to which this device has to be attached to before starting.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should check `ExecStartPre=` and `ExecCondition=`. Looks like they able to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing something similar where the service is getting started before the Luks device under /dev/mapper is getting created.

When I do "systemctl start myservice" it works fine.